# Using Coefficient for Conjugate[variables] (Mathematica ignores my assumptions)

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a sum and I use `Coeffcient[]` to extract certain terms. For example, I want all term in the following sum that contain `h1L1Rr` or `h15i[8]`.

```
test = 2 Sqrt[2] h1L1Rr Y1L + Conjugate[ 6 I Sqrt[2] h1L1Ri Y1L + 6 Sqrt[2] h1L1Rr Y1L + Y15L (3 I Sqrt[2] h15i[3] + I Sqrt[6] h15i[8] + I Sqrt[3] h15i[15] + 3 Sqrt[2] h15r[3] + Sqrt[6] h15r[8] + Sqrt[3] h15r[15])]
 Coefficient[test,h1L1Rr]
 Coefficient[test,h15i[8]]

(* 2 Sqrt[2] Y1L *)
(* 0             *)
```

My problem is that Mathematica ignores the Conjugate terms. I tried several things, because `h1L1Rr` and `h15i[8]` are real, without any success. For example,

```
list={h1L1Rr,h15i[8]}
test2=Simplify[test,Assumptions->list \[Element] Reals ];
Coefficient[test,h1L1Rr]
Coefficient[test,h15i[8]]

(* 2 Sqrt[2] Y1L *)
(* 0             *)
```

Any ideas how I can convince that my list of variables is indeed real and therefore should be collected by `Coefficient[]` would be awesome!

Comment: Look up and try `ComplexExpand`.  Then apply `Coefficient`.